# Why bash script, that must creat and run zabbix server, execute without errors, but result is wrong?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, mariadb

everyone. I`ve started to learn bash and DevOps, lost 2 days, but I can`t understand the following:
**requirments**

- Centos 7
- DB mysql
- zabbix server version 4
- mariadb

I need to write bash script (script at the end of the question), that creates and runs zabbix server (exactly 4 version). When I run the script manually step by step (inserting each command in pwsh by hand) in two ways for db creating (example1 or example2) - it is executed properly: zabbix db is created, all services started, zabbix frontend is working well.
But when I run the script as root user or as local user by command:

```
>sh -c /home/zabbix_server
```

script is finished by:

```
>Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zabbix-server.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-server.service.
>Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zabbix-agent.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service.
>Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.
```

there are no error messages during or at the end of the script, but when I try manually execute the command create db (example1 or example2), it's doesn't matter:

```
#Create DB (example1)
mysql -uroot <<EOF
create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
create user 'zabbix'@'localhost' identified by 'zabbix';
grant all privileges on zabbix.* to 'zabbix'@'localhost';
EOF
#Create DB (example2)
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE zabbix; CREATE USER zabbix@localhost identified by 'zabbix'; GRANT ALL ON zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;"
```

I get the error message: ... db can't be created, zabbix base exist
But the result of the command:

```
>show databases;
```

doesn't show db zabbix in db list.

**script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
setenforce 0
#Install the repository configuration package
rpm -Uvh https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-4.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm
yum clean all
#Install Zabbix server, frontend, agent, database
yum install zabbix-server-mysql -y
yum install zabbix-web-mysql -y
yum install zabbix-agent -y
yum install mariadb-server -y
#Start DB
systemctl start mariadb
#Create DB (example1)
mysql -uroot <<EOF
create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
create user 'zabbix'@'localhost' identified by 'zabbix';
grant all privileges on zabbix.* to 'zabbix'@'localhost';
EOF
#Create DB (example2)
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE zabbix; CREATE USER zabbix@localhost identified by 'zabbix'; GRANT ALL ON zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;"
#Import initial schema and data
zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql zabbix
#Configure the database for Zabbix server
echo DBPassword=zabbix >> /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
#Start zabbix server
systemctl start zabbix-server
#Configure frontend
sed -i 's:# php_value date.timezone.*:php_value date.timezone Europe\/Minsk:g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf;
#Start httpd
systemctl restart zabbix-server zabbix-agent httpd
#Make Zabbix server and agent processes start at system boot
systemctl enable zabbix-server zabbix-agent httpd
```

Comment: Your script is creating the database and user twice. First below `Create DB (example1)` and again below `Create DB (example2)`. The second one gets an error because of the duplication.

Comment: example1 and exaple2 is two different ways to create db. I use example1 or example2, but no in the same time

Comment: Are you logging in to mysql as zabbix user to do 'show databases' ? You would get more debugging info if you add -x to bash in the header i.e #!/usr/bin/env bash -x

Comment: @A.Matrosov : Note that `sh -c /home/zabbix_server` runs the script `zabbix-server` as bash only **if** the script has execute rights **and** a #!-line for bash. If this is not the case, you have to run it with `bash /home/zabbix_server` to get it executed by `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, this may be a good suggestion:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS zabbix;
```

This makes the call idempotent!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the script contains a \r (CR) at the end (0d). Remove it with:

```
tr -d '\r' < old_name_script > new_name_script
```

And the script works fine.
If it will be useful, there is fully working example of the script, that creates zabbix server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Disable SELinux
enforceStatus=getenforse
if [ "$enforceStatus" != "Permissive" ]; then
setenforce 0
fi
#Install the repository configuration package
rpm -Uvh https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-4.0-2.el7.noarch.rpm
yum clean all
#Install Zabbix server, frontend, agent, database, httpd
yum install zabbix-server-mysql -y
yum install zabbix-web-mysql -y
yum install zabbix-agent -y
yum install mariadb mariadb-server -y
yum install httpd -y
#Start and add to autostart DB mariadb
systemctl start mariadb
systemctl enable mariadb.service
#Create DB (example1)
mysql -uroot <<EOF
create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
create user 'zabbix'@'localhost' identified by 'zabbix';
grant all privileges on zabbix.* to 'zabbix'@'localhost';
EOF
#Import initial schema and data
zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql zabbix
#Configure the database for Zabbix server
echo DBPassword=zabbix >> /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
#Configure frontend 
sed -i 's:# php_value date.timezone.*:php_value date.timezone Europe\/Minsk:g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf;
#Start zabbix server processes start at system boot
systemctl restart zabbix-server
systemctl enable zabbix-server
#Start httpd processes start at system boot
systemctl restart httpd
systemctl enable httpd
#Start zabbix-agent processes start at system boot
systemctl restart zabbix-agent
systemctl enable zabbix-agent
#Add permissions to irewall
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10050/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10051/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```